# MapboxMap's controller has cameraPosition equal to null when called by a listener

Tags: flutter, dart, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to add a marker at the camera position. So I need to get the camera's position whenever the user moves trough the map. After a quick research, I found out that it should be easy to setup a listener that get called each time the user moves, and extract the camera position using `controller.cameraPosition`. It looked greatly easy, but the `controller.cameraPosition` is always `null` when the listener get called. Only when the `onMapCreated` function is triggered, it has the right values.

Here's a easy reproducable code sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:mapbox_gl/mapbox_gl.dart';

import 'package:test_01/secretAccessToken.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyMapBoxMap(),
    )
  );
}

class MyMapBoxMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyMapBoxMapState createState() => _MyMapBoxMapState();
}

class _MyMapBoxMapState extends State<MyMapBoxMap> {
  MapboxMapController mapController;

  void _onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    print("On map created: ${mapController.cameraPosition}");
    mapController.addListener(() {
      print(mapController.cameraPosition);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: MapboxMap(
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(42, 42), zoom: 3),
        accessToken: secretAccessToken,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

(The `secretAccessToken` is a private access token obtainable on the mapbox website)

Here's the output's log:

```
...
I/flutter (18328): On map created: CameraPosition(bearing: 0.0, target: LatLng(42.0, 42.0), tilt: 0.0, zoom: 3.0)
...
I/flutter (18328): null
...
```

I am using `mapbox_gl: ^0.8.0`

Am I missing something pretty obvious that I should've read ?
Thanks for reading

Comment: I think controller.cameraPosition works as expected. If the map is not created cameraPosition should be null. Is not it?

Comment: At the moment where onMapCreated is called, the controller.CameraPosition is filled, but when the listener is called, it's always null. (The listener is setup in onMapCreated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. You can read [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/mapbox_gl/latest/mapbox_gl/MapboxMapController-class.html) (on the doc of mapbox_gl) that `cameraPosition`

> Will be null, if MapboxMap.trackCameraPosition is false

Feeling a bit stupid rn